# How to read webserver environment variables using Apache TomEE?

Tags: java, apache-tomee, shibboleth, tomee-7

I am planning to use the Shibboleth SSO Service Provider in my application, which is explained [here](https://www.switch.ch/aai/guides/sp/). It is mentioned, that after a successful login, user information can be

> "read from the webserver environment, e.g. with `$_SERVER['mail']` in PHP".

How do I accomplish this in Java with TomEE?

I am using Apache Web Server in combination with Tomcat, such that servlet requests are forwarded to Tomcat. Is it even possible to access the Apache environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) of mod_proxy_ajp:

> Environment variables whose names have the prefix AJP_ are forwarded to the origin server as AJP request attributes (with the AJP_ prefix removed from the name of the key).

So assuming you configure your Shibboleth SP to decode a SAML Attribute as the webserver environment variable "mail", in your application code you can get the value by using

```
request.getAttribute("AJP_mail")
```